# Installing Ubuntu Server 18.04 w/ RAID 1

Tags: server, system-installation, 18.04, raid

I wish to put up a Ubuntu server for 10 people, mainly for file sharing via samba (for now).

The server, in an [Intel SC5295UP chassis](http://static6.arrow.com/aropdfconversion/a921064d709a6a8f3b3ab9ae47b7d16b882555c/322645322645.pdf), had the old unsupported distro [Dark Star](https://distrowatch.com/table.php?distribution=darkstar). Linux was installed on a RAID logical disk, made from two drives  configured as RAID 1.

I installed the Ubuntu Server 18.04 -Live system from the CD. After choosing the first options, 2 disks appeared to me. I stopped the installations for fear that I would lose what I have.

I delved into the subject and read that I must have a different version of Linux.

1. Is the [alternative version](http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/releases/18.04/release/ubuntu-18.04-server-amd64.iso) for me or "For IBM System with series mainframes, such as IBM LinuxONE"?
2. Can there be a Live version and I should create identical partitions on 2 disks?
3. How much do you recommend the partition and what if I have 250 Gb and 1 Gb disks?
4. Is there any guide on how to get through the installation process for RAID 1?

Comment: The folks here want you to ask one question per post. This way, they build up a database of good answers to good questions. Please split this up into multiple posts by clicking on edit above in grey, and starting with #1 is a good idea.

Comment: A) Do you really have a 1GB drive, or a 1TB drive you want to set up as part of a RAID array? - 

B) Please also provide the motherboard used, as the Intel model number is for an Intel chassis, which could have multiple different motherboards. - 

C) Please advise if there is a RAID controller card in that system, or whether you need software-only RAID.

Answer (score 0):

I have an Intel Server Board S3000AH motherboard. The specification shows that it has only software RAID because I do not have an additional card in it.
I have two 250 GB hard drives and 1 Gb of RAM.

Answer (score 0):

The normal Ubuntu 18.04 server version doesn't come with the RAID tools.  You will need to use the alternate server version from here: http://cdimage.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/releases/bionic/release/